# Override only a certain Index in Array stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I need an Array that stores all visited articles, to insert certain images later on. The function is loaded at `onload` of each page (A page contains one article). This gets it almost, but it saves only the last page I visited. I don't want my function to override all of localStorage, I only want it to override the index which is selected in line number 8

```
var authors = new Array ("lara", "nici", "lena", "johanna", "vivi", "tamara", "luisa", "sarah", "pia");
var article_visited = new Array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var i;
function activate_article ()
  { 
    for (i=0; i<9;i++)
       {
         if (window.location.href.indexOf(authors[i]) > -1)
            {
              localStorage.setItem (article_visited[i], 1);
              article_visited[i] = localStorage.getItem (article_visited[i]);
            }
        }
     localStorage.setItem("final_Array", article_visited);
  }
```

Anyone got an idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting `article_visited` to a new array on every page load.

Try the following, this sets the array to what was previously set so you are not overwriting your previous value. If the item `final_Array` does not exist in local storage then it sets to a new array.

```
var article_visited = localStorage.getItem('final_Array') ? localStorage.getItem('final_Array') : new Array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help! I tried that too.. but my if condition then somehow stops working.. it saves my first visit now, but if I open a new article its not getting into my if condition and adding a new 1 to my array:/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem starts with usage of `localStorage.setItem (article_visited[i], 1);`. This means, you are saving as `setItem(0, 1)` for 0th index and similarly saving as `setItem(0, 1)` for last index because the first argument pass is value and not the array index.

If you change to `localStorage.setItem(i, 1)` and `localStorage.getItem(i)` should not overwrite.

Comment: thanks to you too! I get what you're thinking of, unfortunately it didnt change anything.. its still overriding the whole array, every time I load the function